# Spark newAPIHadoopFile() results in duplicates

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to read in 100 distinct Avro records from disk using `newAPIHadoopFile`, but after collection I end up with a list containing the final record repeated 100 times.

I took note of the API docs which mentioned to map the data first but it makes no difference:

> Note: Because Hadoop's RecordReader class re-uses the same
>   Writable object for each record, directly caching the returned
>   RDD will create many references to the same object. If you plan
>   to directly cache Hadoop writable objects, you should first copy them
>   using a `map` function.

Sample code:

```
JavaPairRDD<AvroKey, NullWritable> testRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(dataSource.getFileDir(), AvroKeyInputFormat.class, AvroKey.class, NullWritable.class, new Configuration());
List<Object> collect = testRDD.map(a -> a._1.datum()).collect();
```

However, using the following seems to print out the records as expected:

```
JavaPairRDD<AvroKey, NullWritable> testRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(dataSource.getFileDir(), AvroKeyInputFormat.class, AvroKey.class, NullWritable.class, new Configuration());
testRDD.foreach(a -> System.out.println(a._1.datum().toString()));
```

I'm using Spark 1.6.

Spark Context is initialised with:

```
SparkConf conf  = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local")
            .setAppName("TestApp")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```